# Use of the different magnetic fields in MRI

Tags: homework-and-exercises, medical-physics

Hi I was wondering if somebody could highlight the purpose of

a) The uniform magnetic field in the MRI scanner

b) The non-uniform magnetic field in the MRI scanner

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ishan and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question fills many books. The very short answer: the static field provides the central resonance, the gradients provide spatial information.

At a most fundamental level, the $B_0$ (uniform) field provides the field that aligns the proton spins and gives them all the same resonant frequency. For a typical 3.0 T MRI scanner, that frequency might be 127 MHz (or slightly less, 123 MHz, for the "really 2.9 but we will call it 3 T" machines of some manufacturers...). Proton resonance (and their time evolution) is the fundamental mechanism used to probe the properties of tissues - but if all protons precess with the same frequency you get no spatial information.

The gradients (typically, X, Y and Z) can be used to locally modify the magnetic field, which will change the frequency of protons across the volume. When you excite at a particular frequency, and you apply a gradient across the imaging volume, there will be just a slab of tissue in which you excite resonance (namely, where the net magnetic field matches the excitation frequency). By changing the magnetic field again before or during read-out, one can further differentiate between the signals from different locations. In this way it is possible to create 3D maps of the properties of tissue.

Start by reading [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_magnetic_resonance_imaging) but recognize that this is a very complex subject - much too broad to be treated properly in the format of this site.